# A question about shear flow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image]This is a exercise problem from my text book:

> 1. Consider a shear flow $\mathbf{u}(x, y)=(U, V),$ where $U=y$ and $V=0$ are the Eulerian velocities along $x$ and $y$ respectively.  at time $t=0,$ consider a material closed loop $\Gamma:$ this is an equilateral triangle $A B C$ with side length $L.$ The side $B C$ is parallel to $x,$ and at $A$ the Eulerian velocity is the largest. Determine the rate of the change of the internal angle $\alpha$ at the vertex $A$.

My approach is to divide angle $\alpha$ to $2$ angles (make vertical lint from $A$ to $BC$), then solve then in their own triangles, however using this method when I treat $\tan(\alpha)=\alpha$ add up $2$ angles, then all $dt$ terms cancels out and only a constant term remains which implies that the angle does not change with time. It's obvious not correct, could anyone tell me what's wrong with my method?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you did.  Please provide a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Let the normal from A to BC hit BC at D.  Then $$\tan{\alpha_1}=\frac{BD}{AD}\tag{1}$$ and $$\tan{\alpha_2}=\frac{DC}{AD}\tag{2}$$AD doesn't change with time but BD and DC do:  $$\frac{d(BD)}{dt}=y_{AD}=h$$ and $$\frac{d(DC)}{dt}=-y_{AD}=-h$$where h=AD is the altitude of the triangle.  So taking the time derivatives of Eqns. 1 and 2 gives:
$$\sec^2{\alpha_1}\frac{d\alpha_1}{dt}=\frac{AD}{AD}=1$$and$$\sec^2{\alpha_2}\frac{d\alpha_2}{dt}=-\frac{AD}{AD}=-1$$

Comment: Yeah that's my approach. I tried to use $\tan \alpha$ to get $\alpha $ in left and right triangles of $AD$ however when I sum $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ up the $dt$ term cancels out. Which leads to a $dt$ term in angular rate change.

Comment: I add a picture of what I did, could you please check where Im wrong?

Comment: Oops.  I actually determined the rate of change of angle B with respect to time.  Ill go back and determine the rate of change of angle C with respect to time,  Their sum will be minus the rate of change of angle A with respect to time.

Comment: I'm not able to decipher what you did.  But, I've amended my answer to adopt your approach.

Comment: So that implies $\alpha$ does not change with time?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what it implies (at least initially).